# How can I recall data from a previous session without cookies?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a page where I enter a name and check a series of checkboxes.  The result is saved to a server-side text file using PHP.

I access the data associated with any particular name by using the following PHP:

```
<?php
$search = $_GET["name"];
$comments = file_get_contents('comments.txt');
$array = explode("~",$comments);

echo "<html>";

foreach($array as $item){
if(strstr($item, $search)){
echo $item;
} }
?>
```

I would like to recall this data at a future date.  When I select a name again, the associated checkboxes would somehow change in css style (to remind me they were checked in a previous session).

```
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="comment" id="AAA" value="Example text.  " onclick="createOrder()"><label for="AAA" onclick="createOrder()" title=
"Example text.">
 example </label></nobr><br>
```

My theoretical solution: On the press of button or some such event, the PHP would search for the selected name, search for AAA in association with that name, and (if found) change the color of label for AAA.

I'm not sure cookies would be appropriate here.  The simple PHP above just echos the data to a page.  Is my suggested method even possible?

To elaborate:
My goal is to enter a name and check boxes. That data is stored in a text file with all other names and checkbox data. Perhaps as such:

```
John Smith AAA FFF RRR
Jill Jones BBB RRR ZZZ
```

On a future session, when John Smith is entered again, the labels for checkboxes with ID AAA, FFF, and RRR will change color to remind me that they were checked last time.

Comment: What does cookies have to do with this? Cookies are for saving data in the client, not getting data from the server. It sounds like what you really need to use is AJAX.

Comment: You  can save your search in php session.

Comment: Can you please elaborate regarding your final goal? I believe that there's a better approach to achieve it.

Comment: I have attempted to elaborate with my edit.  Cookies may have nothing to do with this question.  It was my only guess at how to achieve my goal.  I hope the goal is more clear now.

Comment: this still sounds like a use for AJAX. When the user presses the button, you send the name to the server in an AJAX request. The server script searches the file, and replies with the list of labels. Then the Javascript changes the colors of those label fields.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with AJAX, but I am open to using it.  Can my existing code be modified?  And how?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the php session variable to store temporary data.

session_start();
   $_SESSION[$search] = $checkboxStates;

The session variable needs to be initialized and can be used across multiple user requests. Typically session relies on cookie so data will be lost when the browser clear the cookie.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I would need the data to be permanent.  That is, I need to access it in sessions that may be months apart or on different computers.  This is why I thought to save it to a text file on the server.

Comment: If this case you can store the checkbox states into a file (using json_encode for ex) like you did for comments, and the simplest way would be to name the file by the search query, to easily retrieve or modify it. Note that the checkbox states will be the same for any users.

Comment: I would make a `md5()` hash of the query and use that as the filename.

Comment: Yes any string should be encoded if stored as a filename,  I also like to use function like urlencode that keep the filename readable.

Comment: Can anyone point me to a demonstration?  I can't understand how to apply this to the above code.